# C++ most efficient way to cast a very large number of vectors doubles to vectors of chars

Tags: c++, vector, casting, stdvector

I have some code that makes some computations and then returns a lot (thousands or even hundreds of thousands) of `vectors` of `vectors` of `doubles` (matrices). These values are already rounded to the nearest integer and will never exceed the max size of a byte. The matrices will be flattened to one dimensional `vectors` and then written as binary data to a file. However, I don't want to store these values as `doubles`, since they would take up more space. They need to be stored as `chars` but the code that returns them will always give me doubles, so I was wondering what is the fastest way of casting all the `doubles` to `chars`.

I'm specifically looking for a way to convert the `vectors` of one type to another, because vectors are easy to be written to files.

Comment: Are these values signed?

Comment: vectors are stored contiguously. A double has more space than a char. You can't in-place cast a `vector<double>` to a `vector<char>` Your best bet is probably to have your vectors simply be returned as `vector<char>` ahead of time. Either way, you're going to need to do some copying.

Comment: @Cameron yes, they are signed.

Comment: @AndyG yes, I am aware of that. Can't really change the code that returns the `doubles`, because it is used by many other methods who expect `doubles`. Perhaps I should write a `char`version of the method?

Comment: What is the permitted range of the doubles? Is it 0 to 256? Or -128 to 127? Or what?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `std::copy` or `std::transform`? Seems like it should be very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your vector without problem in this mode:

```
const char* VectToChar = (char*)&Vector[0];
```

In the following code you can find a full example. Warning this code is valid only for vector data reading and not for writing!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    vector<double> Vector;

    Vector.push_back(10.2);
    Vector.push_back(15.2);


    // You can use this method only for data reading, no writing!!
    const char* VectToChar = (char*)&Vector[0];


    // Test
    double d0 = *((double*)VectToChar);
    double d1 = *((double*)(VectToChar+sizeof(double)));
    printf("%f, %f", d0, d1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a `char` version of the last method in the calculation. Easier than having to copy or doing more complex stuff.